# BEM css - Mix elements/modifiers

Tags: element, modifier, bem

I've a question about BEM structure. Is it semantically correct to mix elements/modifiers? I have a hero and portfolio module. I want to use an portfolio__item in the hero module, but it should use the base styling of the hero__item. Is this an correct way of doing this, is it 'allowed' to mix these elements?

```
<section class="hero hero--collage hero--bottom-decoration">    
    <div class="portfolio__item hero__item hero__item--animated">
        <a href="http://www.google.nl"> 
            <div class="hero__hover">
                <span class="hero__hover__content h1">Hover title</span>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.google.nl" class="hero__image">
        </a>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio__item">
        <a href="http://www.google.nl"> 
            <img src="http://www.google.nl" class="hero__image">
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want. But BEM methodology says:

> block set namespace

It's a little messy to read this. 
I can't understand it at a glance.
The goal of BEM - **separate blocks** so you don't need write same block again. And the same for styles. With this and modifiers you can reuse and tweak every block you need.

> You can mix block and elements

```
<img src="http://www.google.nl" class="block-name hero__image">
```

So on 'block-name' you can match styles for every instance. On hero__image or another element you can match unique styles.

> You can't create elements of elements

You don't need write 2 lvl. Cause name of your block set namespace.

```
<span class="hero__hover__content h1">Hover title</span>
```

Just

```
<span class="hero__hover-content h1">Hover title</span>
```

---

docs: https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/

Comment: Thanks! I'm starting to see the advantage of BEM more and more. At first it's a bit "overwhelming" with all the class names.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it semantically correct to mix elements/modifiers" - I assume you want to place `portfolio__item` element within the `hero` block - it's not a good thing. You can nest a block within a block but not block's element within another block's element.

You can use modifiers to `hero__item` element thought like

```
<div class="hero__item hero__item--portfolio"></div>
```

which will change it's style.

Comment: The `portfolio__item` has almost the same styling as the `hero--collage hero__item`. So to avoid duplicated css i thought i could use the `portfolio__item` inside the `hero--collage`. Is the best way to extend (i'm using sass) the styling from the `portfolio__item` to the `hero__item--portfolio`?

Comment: If you use LESS/SASS you can create a generic virtual class like .virtual-1 and extend another classes with it like:
.hero--collage {
 .virtual-1;
// custom styles
}
.portfolio__item {
  .virtual-1;
// custom styles
}

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i was aware of the extend. But a lot of people don't recommend to use extends. But in this case i guess it's ok, because almost all classes are at root level because of the BEM structure.